# perl sdl module install fail

Tags: linux, perl

i'm used ubuntu 14.04 lts
.
and，the module already download

1:Keyboard input

```
$ sudo -s cpan SDL 1>stdout.txt  2>stderr.txt
```

stdout.txt:

```
 1 Reading '/home/freakcoco/.cpan/Metadata'
 2   Database was generated on Fri, 04 Sep 2015 16:29:02 GMT
 3 Running install for module 'SDL'
 4 Checksum for /home/freakcoco/.cpan/sources/authors/id/F/FR/FROGGS/SDL-2.546.tar.gz ok
 5 ---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
 6 ----          FROGGS/SDL-2.546.tar.gz         ----
 7     Alien::SDL [build_requires]
 8 Running install for module 'Alien::SDL'
 9 Checksum for /home/freakcoco/.cpan/sources/authors/id/F/FR/FROGGS/Alien-SDL-1.446.tar.gz ok
10 Configuring F/FR/FROGGS/Alien-SDL-1.446.tar.gz with Build.PL
11 Welcome to Alien::SDL module installation
12 -----------------------------------------
13 checking operating system... linux
14 checking for cc... yes
15 checking build system type... x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
16 checking platform specific module... using 'My::Builder::Unix'
17 Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site]
18   FROGGS/Alien-SDL-1.446.tar.gz
19   /usr/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site -- NOT OK
20   FROGGS/SDL-2.546.tar.gz
21   Has already been unwrapped into directory /home/freakcoco/.cpan/build/SDL-2.546-1przxQ
22 Warning: Prerequisite 'Alien::SDL => 1.446' for 'FROGGS/SDL-2.546.tar.gz' failed when processing 'FROGGS/Alien-SDL-1.446.tar.gz' with 'writemakefile => NO '/usr/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site' returned status 512'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
23 Configuring F/FR/FROGGS/SDL-2.546.tar.gz with Build.PL
24 Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site]
25   FROGGS/SDL-2.546.tar.gz
26   /usr/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site -- NOT OK
```

stderr.txt:

```
 1 Unknown option: installdirs
 2 Too early to specify a build action 'site'.  Do 'Build site' instead.
 3 Can't locate Alien/SDL.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Alien::SDL module) (@INC contains: inc /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at Build.PL line 12.
 4 BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Build.PL line 12.
```

2:Keyboard input (install the Alien::SDL module)

```
$ sudo -s cpan SDL 1>stdout2.txt  2>stderr2.txt
```

stdout2.txt

```
 1 Reading '/home/freakcoco/.cpan/Metadata'
 2   Database was generated on Fri, 04 Sep 2015 16:29:02 GMT
 3 Running install for module 'Alien::SDL'
 4 Checksum for /home/freakcoco/.cpan/sources/authors/id/F/FR/FROGGS/Alien-SDL-1.446.tar.gz ok
 5 Configuring F/FR/FROGGS/Alien-SDL-1.446.tar.gz with Build.PL
 6 Welcome to Alien::SDL module installation
 7 -----------------------------------------
 8 checking operating system... linux
 9 checking for cc... yes
10 checking build system type... x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
11 checking platform specific module... using 'My::Builder::Unix'
12 Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site]
13   FROGGS/Alien-SDL-1.446.tar.gz
14   /usr/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site -- NOT OK
```

stderr2.txt:

```
 1 Unknown option: installdirs
 2 Too early to specify a build action 'site'.  Do 'Build site' instead.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a bug in Alien::SDL and its use of Getopt::Long (a similar issue was fixed [here](https://github.com/OpenGuides/OpenGuides/pull/71)).

You can try this workaround:

If you run `sudo cpan` and in that shell `o conf mbuildpl_arg`, you should get something like this:

```
    mbuildpl_arg       [--installdirs site]
Type 'o conf' to view all configuration items
```

If that is the case, run `o conf mbuild_arg installdirs=site` (which should output `mbuildpl_arg       [installdirs=site]`), then `o conf commit`, then exit the cpan shell. I believe that should bypass the option parsing issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found that removing my .cpan folder and reinstalling Module::Build before Alien::SDL resoleved this problem:

rm -rf ~/.cpan